# WPF scrollviewer overview control

Tags: wpf, navigation, scrollviewer

in my WPF application I use Scrollviewer to show a diagram.
The diagram can be pretty big and complex and usually you can see only a smart part of a diagram in the Scrollviewer control.

To facilitate the diagram navigation I will create a control which should contain the whole diagram picture. If you click on specific place in this control the Scrollviewer should scroll the diagram to this place.

[Something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oPvb.jpg)

What is the easiest way to do that?
Many thanks and sorry for my terrible English.

Comment: Easiest is to buy it or locate an acceptable free version. What you want is called a "zoom content control".  Several options are indexed on your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 1):

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="TheScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Image x:Name="FullImage" Source="Test.jpg" Stretch="None"></Image>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Image x:Name="ThumbnailImage" Height="100" Source="Test.jpg" MouseDown="ThumbnailImage_OnMouseDown"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void ThumbnailImage_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.GetPosition(ThumnailImage);

    var horOffset = position.X / ThumnailImage.ActualWidth * FullImage.ActualWidth;
    var verOffset = position.Y / ThumnailImage.ActualHeight * FullImage.ActualHeight;

    TheScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(horOffset);
    TheScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(verOffset);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly there is no "fix" diagram picture - the diagram will be generated dynamically and is changeable.
But maybe there is the way to get the "full" Scrollviewer-picture and bind it to the Image control?

Comment: Just change the `Source` property of the `Image` control according to the changing picture. The `Image` control should be fixed. Right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. You can either using binding or just setting the `FullImage.Source=xxx; ThumbnailImage.Source=xxx;` in the code-behind.